# Как в kendoMultiSelect сделать выбранными все элементы из источника данных?

Tags: javascript, kendo

Как в kendoMultiSelect сделать выбранными все элементы из источника данных?

Использую так:

```
var elements = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetElements_Pattern", "Plan")',
                    data: {
                        "planid": '@Model[0].ToString()'
                    },
                    dataType: "json"                    
                }
            }
        });

        elements.read();
        elementslist.setDataSource(elements);
```

Знаю что очистить или выбрать конкретные:

elementslist.value([]);

Но как через этот оператор указать чтобы по умолчанию были выбраны все элементы? Или может это свойство отдельное?

Comment: смотри матчасть http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource

Comment: Смотрел, плохо разбираюсь в тематике, поэтому и прошу помощи. Но все равно спасибо за ссылку на справку!